# Is there a way to make a Marionette View listen for events on itself via the events hash?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm having trouble figuring out how to quickly, and simply attach a listener for events triggered on a Backbone.Marionette view.

I can currently accomplish what I'm looking for by adding a listener via `.on`, but is there a quick way via the events or triggers hashes? Something like this seems like it should work but doesn't:

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({      
    triggers: {
        "click .close": "menu:close"
    },

    events: {
        "menu:close @": "close",
    },

    close: {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
There is actually a (simple) way to do exactly what you want.

```
// Itemview
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        Marionette.bindEntityEvents(this, this, this.events);  
    },
    template: "#item",
    triggers: {
        "click .btn": "menu:performAction"
    },
    events: {
        "menu:performAction": "performAction"
    },
    performAction: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

In short this binds your events attribute containing the hashes to the views events.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8T68P/
Documentation: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.functions.md#marionettebindentityevents

**Old answer**
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/K5TTQ/

Listening to events like that won't work indeed. And if you happen to use the `.on` method from within your view. Please use `listenTo`. That will be cleaned up properly when the view is closed. Like this:

```
// Itemview
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var view = this;
        view.listenTo(view, "menu:performAction", view.performActionFromListenTo);   
    },
    template: "#item",
    triggers: {
        "click .btn": "menu:performAction"
    },        
    performActionFromListenTo: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. It would be nice to have a hash for listening to triggers. Guess I'll have to extend it to do that myself!

Comment: Or add it as a request here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette :)